# Motorola XOOM emulator?

Tags: android-emulator, motorola, xoom

I have no motorola XOOM but I must try an app for it. I ' m looking for emulator of XOOM ? How can I set up emulator in eclipse ?

Comment: you can check this.
it show how to create emulator for nexus S and xoom http://buildcontext.com/blog/2011/android-browser-emulator-windows-7-nexus-s-xoom-tablet

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the Android SDK? If so, just create a 3.1 AVD with the 10.1 screen profile.

See [Here](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/devices/index.html) for more information.